# Выделить конкретный View и затенить все остальные на экране

Tags: android

Делаю режим обучения для игры. Игрок переходит в режим обучения, где ему показывается общий экран, затем, по нажатию, один за другим подсвечиваются нужные `View`. При этом весь остальной экран затеняется (но немного виден). Думаю, вы видели такое в играх.

Пробовал использовать `foreground`, но он работает только с API 23 или только с `FrameLayout`. А у меня минимальный API 14 и много кастомных `View`, иногда несколько-слойные и со своими бэками.

Нашел вот такую [библиотеку](https://github.com/Commit451/ForegroundViews), но это не совсем то, что нужно.

В идеале хочу такой метод/библиотеку (чтобы не писать самому), которая принимает `View` и создаёт черный полупрозрачный foreground на весь экран, исключая область переданного `View`.

Может это делается как-то проще? В общем, помогите.

Пример разметки:

[image: Пример разметки]

Как я хочу, чтобы получалось:

[image: Как должно получиться]
[image: Как должно получиться]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покопавшись по глубинам eSO нашел решение, которое для меня работает. Кастомный `FrameLayout`, который добавляется в корневой `RelativeLayout` последним (поверх всего):

```
public class OverlayView extends FrameLayout {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private int paddings, offset;
    private Rect rect;

    public OverlayView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public OverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        rect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
        offset = (int) (-24 *  getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        paddings = (int) getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.paddings);
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            createWindowFrame();
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    protected void createWindowFrame() {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas osCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        RectF outerRectangle = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark));
        osCanvas.drawRect(outerRectangle, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
        osCanvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }

    public void setView(View v) {
        int xStart = getRelativeLeft(v) - paddings;
        int yStart = getRelativeTop(v) - paddings +offset;
        int xEnd = xStart + v.getWidth() + paddings * 2;
        int yEnd = yStart + v.getHeight() + paddings * 2;
        rect = new Rect(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
        createWindowFrame();
        postInvalidate();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isInEditMode() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        bitmap = null;
    }

    private int getRelativeLeft(View myView) {
        if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
            return myView.getLeft();
        else
            return myView.getLeft() + getRelativeLeft((View) myView.getParent());
    }

    private int getRelativeTop(View myView) {
        if (myView.getParent() == myView.getRootView())
            return myView.getTop();
        else
            return myView.getTop() + getRelativeTop((View) myView.getParent());
    }
}
```

`offset` нужен, чтобы изображение не смещалось по оси y.

Использование: 
`screen.setView(myView);`

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь поможет ;)